# React onclick hide this component on non-class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have rendered a couple of components like this:

```
<MyComponent />

<MyComponent />
```

Here is the component code. 
It has a button that is supposed to hide itself when clicked.

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = (props) => <div>

    <div>
       <button onClick={hideme}>Click to hide this component</button>
    </div>


</div>;



function hideme() {
    // code here 
}

export default MyComponent;
```

My question is...

Knowing that this is not a class based component.

How to I hide each individually when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Blockquote

Try using React hooks its a new feature it should help  [React Hooks Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple solutions to this approach.

One is to use the event object you get passed from the `onClick` method on your function component, and set the style of the desired object, see here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vwn0k2wzl

Another is to have a parent component (container) handle the state of that button, and pass the functionality to hide it to the view component, this is a more common and more 'react' way to do this (managing and handling state from the top-down), see here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lxx627l7rl

You could also hide this component with for example `display: none`, but the latter method really removed your component from the tree.

Comment: This looks good but it's hiding the clicked button and not the component

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean in your state which determines if you return something in your render function or not:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        hidden: false
    }
}

render() {

    if(this.state.hidden){
        return null;
    }

    return <div>
            <div>
             <button onClick={() => this.setState({hidden: true})}>Click to hide this component</button>
            </div>
           </div>;
}
```

Comment: You can't do this on a non class component

Comment: My bad.. I thought you meant non-css-class component. Implying you need to hide it without css

Answer (score 0):

If you do this to learn how React works internally you can try the following:

```js
const MyComponent = props => (
  <div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={hideme}>Click to hide this component</button>
    </div>
  </div>
);

function hideme(e) {
  const target = e.currentTarget;
  let instance =
    target[
      Object.keys(target).find(key => key.startsWith("__reactInternalInstance"))
    ];
  while (instance.tag) {
    instance = instance.return;
  }
  instance.child.stateNode.style.display = "none";
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your parent component is class  you can do something  like this

```
class MyParentComponent etxends React.Component {
   state = {
     isShow: true
  }
   hideHandler =  () =>  
      this.setState({isShow: false})

   render(){
       return(
          <MyComponent isShow={this.state.isShow} hideHandler={this.hideHandler} />
       )
   }

}
```

this is child non classe component

```
const MyComponent = props =>  (
  <div> 
        { props.isShow && <button onClick={props.hideHandler}>hide</button>
 </div>
)
```